# How to save LibreOffice Paragraph Heading style as a style template?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, styles

In LibreOffice Writer, I have created a nice paragraph heading style:

[image]

How can I save this style as a style template so it is available as a style template in new Writer documents? I have not found any commands to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Saving a template with a style worked for me in LO 7:

1. Start with an empty Writer document.
2. Create your paragraph style. It now shows up in the right-hand pane.
3. *File -> Templates -> Save As Template.* I saved mine under *Styles.*
4. Close and restart LibreOffice.
5. *File -> Templates -> Open Template.* Select your template. Now the paragraph style is available.

Comment: This saves the WHOLE document as a DOCUMENT TEMPLATE. This allows me to use this heading style only on a FRESH document. But I need to use this heading style on ANY document.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't asking about a "style template" then. Maybe you want to load a style from one document into another as explained at https://documentation.libreoffice.org/assets/Uploads/Documentation/en/GS5.2/HTML/GS5203-StylesAndTemplates.html#__RefHeading__6250_424592115.